# Access a dynamic layout id kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to be able to access a layouts id in order to add shapes to it. The problem is that the id of the layout is always changing. How would I get the id so that I can change that specific layout?

code:

```
can = self.root.get_screen("three")
...
        get_score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')

        new_pos = can.pos
        for x in range(-1, get_score): # had to use -1 to get correct amount of shapes
            if x % 10 == 0:
                layout = GridLayout(id=str(x), cols=1, size_hint= (None,None))
                can.ids.my_box.add_widget(layout)

            with can.ids.my_box.ids.x.canvas:
                Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
                rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30, 30))
            new_pos[0] += rect.size[1]
            new_pos[0] += rect.size[0]

        for child in can.ids.my_box.children: #used to check how many cols are added
            print(child.id)
```

error: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: Unfortunately, the `id` used in the `ids` dictionary can only be created in `kv` language. Setting `id=str(x)` will not add it to the `ids` dictionary.

Comment: @JohnAnderson is there a way around needing the id to draw on the canvas?

Comment: What is your `with can.ids.my_box.ids.x.canvas:` intended to do when x is not a multiple of 10? For example, when x is -1 and a new `GridLayout` is not created?

Comment: Shapes will be drawn on a new column. I planned to have there be a column for every 10 rectangles. @JohnAnderson

Comment: Except for the fact that `layout` will be undefined for x<10, you can just use `with layout.canvas:`.

Comment: Actually, `layout` will only be undefined for x at -1.